# Converting YYYYMMDD8 to DATE9 format?

Tags: date, sas, type-conversion

I need to convert a string in YYYYMMDD format into a numeric DATE9 format in SAS.

I can convert the string to YYYYMMDD8, but am struggling to then convert that into DATE9 format. I thought it would be a case of just putting in a format statement for the variable and setting it as DATE9 since it is already in a numeric date format, but doing so just produces asterisks.

I've tried to reproduce some example code. The dataset date1 is provided. I've converted it to YYYYMMDD8. as per step 2. It's step 3 I cannot get to work. I've tried accepted solutions provided by answers to similar questions, but I can't get it to work. So I may be doing something wrong.

So in short, I need either a working version of Step 3, or a simplified Step 2 that converts the string to date9 in one step.

```
* STEP 1 - Provided;
data date1;
    FORMAT file_date $8.;
    file_date = '20191209';
run;

* Step 2 - Convert to YYYYMMDD8.;
PROC SQL;
    CREATE TABLE date2 AS
    SELECT INPUT(file_date,yyyymmdd8.) AS file_date2 FORMAT YYYYMMDD8.
    FROM date1;

* Step 3 - Convert to DATE9. (Results in asterisks in place of the actual date);
DATA date3;
    SET date2;
    FORMAT file_date3 date9.;
    file_date3 = file_date2;
RUN;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is the format `yyyymmdd` does not exist, it's just `yymmdd`. For simplicity working with SAS dates, you should use the informat `anydtdte`. So step 2 can be simplified to the following:

```
proc sql;
create table date2 as
select input(file_date,anydtdte8.) as file_date2 format=date9.
from date1;
quit;
```